# Question about how a topology is defined

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have an exercise that defines a topology this way:

$$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{1,2,3,...,n\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}$$

I understand that in $\{\{1,2,3,...,n\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ there's only **one set**, and it depends on what $n$ we choose. For example, if we take $n=3$, our topology is $$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{1,2,3\}\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}.$$

Am I right? If not, how this has to be understood?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you have one of those sets for each $n$. The variable $n$ is an index variable.

Comment: No. The topology is the collection of all sets of the form $\{1,2,3,...n\}$ and the empty set and $\mathbb{N}$. For example, $\{1,2,3\}\in\tau$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\in\tau$

Comment: Then it's $\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{1\}\cup\{1,2\}\cup\{1,2,3\}\cup...\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}$ right?

By the way, what is wrong with my question?

Comment: That's a fun topology. Notice that the constant sequence $(1)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to any other numbers.

Comment: Not quite...$\{\{1\}\}\neq \{1\}$

Comment: Your topology has infinitely many sets.

Comment: Perfect! Please answer my question so I can choose an answer.

Comment: $\{ S(n): n\in \Bbb N\}$  means the set of $all$ those and $only$  those $S(n)$ for which $n\in \Bbb N.$ ... So $\{\{1,...,n\}:n\in \Bbb N\}=$ $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},...(etc.)...\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $n$ is just an index variable.

So the topology has open sets of the form $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ for each positive integer $n$.

Thus, the topology is
$$\tau=\{{\large{\varnothing}},\mathbb{N},\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},...\}$$
Of course, you should check to make sure the axioms are satisfied.

- Is the empty set open?$\\[4pt]$

  Is the whole space $\mathbb{N}$ open?$\\[4pt]$

  Is the intersection of two open sets open?$\\[4pt]$

  Is an arbitrary union of open sets open?$\\[4pt]$

The checks are routine, but you should at least think them through.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that in {{1,2,3,...,n}:n∈N} there's **only one** set, and it depends on what n we choose.

No.  You understand wrong and that is exactly what it *doesn't* mean.

That would be $\{\{1,2,3,..... n\}:$ for **some**  $n \in \mathbb N\}$.

It is understood that this notation means $\{\{1,2,3,.... n\}:$ for **every** $n \in \mathbb N\}$

So this set is infinite  and is equal to $\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}...... \{1, 2, 3...... k\}, \{1,2,3,......., k+1\},.......\}$.